# getApplicationContext() method NullPointerException in GoogleApiManager

Tags: android, firebase, google-api, firebase-performance

I launched the app a few days ago. And I'm using FireBase in my app. But some time ago I have an unknown crash.

I did not know where the error occurred when I checked the log. Because it seems to be an error in the Google API, not in my code.

I looked for an issue similar to this one, but I could not find it. It's been a few days since the error occurred and it's still not resolved.

I've upgraded all versions of the modules related to the Google API. I do not know any other way around that. 
And I'm using the app obfuscation service(not proguard), and I'm a little suspicious.

here is my gradle file dependencies

// project level gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5' 
    }
```

// app level gradle

```
dependencies {
 androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.38.1'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'
    //Firebase Crashlytics
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.const' +
            'raint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.kakao.sdk:kakaolink:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.5.1'
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4+@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
    implementation 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:2.0.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here is firebase crash report result.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.zab(Unknown Source:8)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init>(Unknown Source:44)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi.<init>(Unknown Source:53)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zze.<init>(Unknown Source:8)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.clearcut.zze.zzb(Unknown Source:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.clearcut.ClearcutLogger.anonymousLogger(Unknown Source:2)
       at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzd.zzbd(Unknown Source:46)
       at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source:202)
       at com.google.firebase.perf.internal.zze.run(Unknown Source:2)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Also, below case.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(Unknown Source:163)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Many users are already experiencing discomfort. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Let me know if you have more information to solve this problem.

Comment: If you think this is a bug in a Firebase library, please file a bug report with Firebase.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature

Comment: I sent a bug report as you said. I hope firebase will give me a good answer.

Comment: would you like to share your finding? Or share the link to bug report.

Comment: I sent a bug report to Google, but I couldn't get a good answer. 
So I just upgraded the Firebase module. It worked.